# How to show popup dialog box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem creating a small dialogue box to show when I've clicked the picture. Now my popup content just shows below the picture. Below is my coding:

```js
function showpopup() {
    document.getElementById("popupwindow").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```html
<style>
.hidden {display:none}
</style>



<span class="profile"><img width="200" height="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hxa.png" style="margin-top: 30px;" onclick="showpopup()"></img></span>
<div id="popupwindow" class="hidden">
<p style="color:black;">LMS short explanation</p>
</div>
```

Actually, I want the result like below the picture, the popup content can show in the small dialog box.

[image: output1]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Refer this:

---

```js
function showpopup() {
  let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltiptext");
  let visible = tooltip.style.display;
  if (visible == "none") {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-family: open-sans-regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
  outline: none;
}

.tooltip.bottom .arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.tooltip .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #43b02a;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<img width="200" height="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hxa.png" onclick="showpopup()"></img>
<div id="tooltiptext" class="bottom tooltip" style="display: none;">
  <div class="arrow">
  </div>
  LMS short explanation
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the css for pop-ups.
position, top, left, z-index, background color, width, height and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you show me a sample based on my coding?

Comment: they are popularly called "modals" and "tooltips", you can either write them yourself, or just pick up code from the internet, it's just a google away.

Comment: look here, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_top)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip.tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
.hidden{
display: none;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Top Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip" onClick="showpopup()">Hover over me
  <span id="popupwindow" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
<script>
function showpopup() {
    document.getElementById("popupwindow").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My side needs to click then show the dialog box content, cannot using a mouse hover to show the content.

Comment: you can use same logic, just remove hover css and add your click logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showpopup() {
    let popup = document.getElementById("popupwindow");
    let display = popup.style.display;
    if (display == "none") {
        popup.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
        popup.style.display = "none";
    }
}
<style>
    #popupwindow {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 99;
    top: -90px;
    left: -150px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.profile {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
</style>

<div>
    <span class="profile"><img width="200" height="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hxa.png" style="margin-top: 30px;" onclick="showpopup()"></img></span>
    <div id="popupwindow" class="hidden">
        <p style="color:black;">LMS short explanation</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble with the snippets editor so i can't post it properly.
but , here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anuragshukla01/pen/wvzMpZz) regarding your code.

you must enclose all html in a div and the change the postion relative to it.
for the popup , you have to style it with borders,margin,background,etc.

If anyone can correct it then please make the snippet above working.

Comment: Don't add html, css and js together. There are different places to write them in the snippet editor.